# train/validate/test split for time series anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection, train-test-split

I'm trying to perform a multivariate time series anomaly detection. I have training data that consists of "normal" data. I train on this data and detect anomalies on the test set that contains normal + anomalous data. My understanding is that it would be wrong to tweak the model hyperparameters based on the results from the test set.

What would the train/validate/test set look like to train and evaluate a time-series anomaly detector?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming but about ML methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing very specific to anomaly detection here. You neeed to split the testing data into one or more validation and test sets, while making sure they are reasonably independent (no information leakage between them).